# JBoss on cloud, any cheap way to get the enterprise version

Tags: amazon-web-services, jboss, openshift, rhel

Is it possible to get JBoss AS on cloud as part of the install. I don't want to maintain servers, just want to use JBoss AS (the fancy shmancy enterprise version).

The options that I see are.
-Use JBoss Community version on some VPS on even Amazon AWS RHEL image (not so cloudy)
-Use OpenShfit
-Buy all the ingredients and plug them into my wall.

Any suggestions to easily/cheaply run a production ready Jboss AS instance would work.

Not sure if this question belongs here. Mod, go ahead and suggest.

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift is a great option. I highly recommend you try it out.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift now offers AS 7.1 and EAP 6 versions of JBoss

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/), they offer both a Tomcat container as well as a fully support JBoss container